# Aggregates with Event Sourcing and CQRS

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, cqrs, event-sourcing, materialized-views

In order to process large amounts of telemetry data and still be able to perform quick queries on the data, I'm adopting the Event Sourcing / CQRS patterns using Azure Functions and Azure Cosmos DB.

In my architecture, the inbound telemetry stream gets stored in a Cosmos DB Collection acting as event store.

To create materialized views of the raw telemetry data, I use another Azure Function with Cosmos DB Trigger which gets active on all new documents stored in my event store performing transformations on those documents.

This is quite easy working on a document per document basis. 
Where it get's tricky is, when I need to reference other documents in order to calculate my materialized view.

For example, when the received telemetry events contain relative counter values (e.g. energy used in a particular operation). In my materialized view I want to have a document containing a total sum of all energy consumption.

Now an easy implementation would be to look at the current state of this document in my materialized view and just increment this value by the newly received value.

The problem which i could get using this approach is when i have to recalculate my materialized views because in a future version i need to generate some additional views.

For recalculation, I would simply touch all related documents I want to recalculate in my event store, triggering the Azure Function which calculates the materialized views again. This would result in documents entering this Azure Function which were processed before.

When recalculation occurs, my counter would now not be accurate anymore if I simply increment my sum as documents that are already part of the sum would get added again.

Ways to solve this recalculation-scenario (i thought of) would be:

- track all the source documents that are part of the sum and ignore
  events for documents that are already part of the sum
- track sequence number of the latest telemetry event which was already part of the sum and ignore events with a sequence number lower than the one which is already part of the sum when recalculation occurs.

Could you give me some advice on how to properly solve that kind of scenarios?

Comment: Usually, when materialized view is recalculated, the old value is just deleted and the whole calculation starts from scratch. Replaying same event multiple time into the same calculation doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Mikhail! In the replay-scenario, your suggestion would be a good solution but i think i need some level of idemopotency for calculating this kind of materialized views when i take the "at-least-once"-delivery-behavior of messages through changefeed into account. Given this, it could happen to me during normal execution that messages get delivered multiple times. When happens, my sums will be incorrect. Do you have any suggestions for those situations?

Comment: You can store a reasonable amount of last applied event's IDs - to make sure no events were applied twice.

Comment: Also, if your write side uses optimistic locking, you will have aggregateID and a sequental version in each event. Then you can track what version your aggregates were in read-model. And if you have an event missing, or delivered twice - you can track this.

Comment: @RomanEremin thank you for your comments. So you would agree that the 2 ways i thought of solving this would be valid ways to handle those scenarios?

Comment: @MarkusS, yes if you event bus delivers "at-least-once". But I agree with Mikhail - if you change the read model code, you should just rebuild it from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to summarize the comments by @Mikhail and @RomanEremin and my thoughts, this would be the way to handle those scenarios:

In case of recalculating views:

- Delete existing aggregates and build from scratch replaying the
  events in the event store.

In case of event bus delivering "at-least-once" (the way Azure functions with CosmosDb Trigger behave as a result of underlying ChangeFeedProcessor):

- Version 1: Keep track of event ids (document ids) which are part of the aggregate in aggregation document and ignore events that are already part of the aggregate.
- Version 2: Provide a sequential version (sequence number) of the source event and store the version the aggregate is based on in the aggregation document. When calculating the aggregate, check this sequence number against the sequence number of the event. If the event has a lower sequence number than the aggregation document: ignore, otherwise recalculate aggregate and update sequence number the aggregate is based on.